# Pycharm venv from different python versions

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, python-venv

I am using Pycharm on Windows 10. I have an old Python installed using Anaconda (3.8) and a newer version of Python that I installed thanks to the official installer (3.11).

The issue is that I have two different project on Pycharm, one using a venv based on 3.8 and one based on 3.11. However, it seems like I can only use the venv of the python to whom the PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME is pointed to.

e.g. If My PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME is pointed to the 3.11, when I am running the scripts using the venv that was created with my 3.8 python, I got the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
Python runtime state: core initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python3113\lib\io.py", line 54, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'text_encoding' from 'io' (unknown location)
```

If I change the PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME so that they point to the 3.8, it works perfectly

I thought that using venv allowed to detach completely from the system preferences, so why does my environment variable have an influence on my venv ?

Is it an issue from my side or it is not possible to seamlessly change venv this way ?

Thank you !

Comment: If you call `where python` you may understand. I would suggest to not have any python.exe on your path / the output of  `where python` as long as you have not activated an environment.

Comment: The entire point of `venv` is to set your **environment variables** so that they all agree to use some other version of Python.  But if you then go ahead and specifically set the environment variables inside a venv, now they don't agree with each other, and you get errors like this.

Comment: @JohnGordon Then how can I have several versions of python and switch between venv seamlessly on Pycharm ?

Comment: @fischmalte isn't PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME required for Pycharm and else ?

Comment: If you want to switch between several versions of python, the  way to do that is to exit out of the current venv and then activate a different one.  You would have one separate venv for each version of python you want to use.

Comment: I understand that, however the venv has issue depending on which python has a path set in my windows. I can only create venv 311 with pycharm if the python 311 is in the path, same for the 38. And even then I have issues with pycharm when using the python venv in pycharm depending on which python is in the path

Answer (score 0):

> If My PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME is pointed to the 3.11, when I am running the scripts using the venv that was created with my 3.8 python

That's expected. You are trying to run Python 3.8 interpreter while passing it Python 3.11 standard library. Everything naturally blows up. In general, you should not manually alter `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME`.

There are several ways to switch an interpreter in PyCharm

1. For the whole project in **Settings | Project ... | Project Interpreter**

[image]

2. For the whole project via the bottom-left interpreter widget

[image]

3. For a given Run Configuration in **Run | Edit Configurations**

[image]

Comment: So I have several issue, if I want to create a 3.11 venv but my windows path is set to the 3.8 it won't work. Moreover, if I successfully created a 3.11 venv with pycharm but my windows path is set to 3.8 my programs won't work either.

This means that both the windows and pycharm needs to be set at the same version, which defeats greatly the convenience of changing interpreter version with pycharm easily

Comment: @th0mash Would you mind explaining why you feel the need to set `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` globally in your system? Right now, it sounds like you are shouting yourself in a leg for no good reason. E.g., I've never set `PYTHONHOME` manually in my career and very rarely `PYTHONPATH` and only locally for some shell sessions.